# How to make an item of a SurfaceListBox not selectable?

Tags: wpf, xaml, pixelsense

In a WPF application I'am using a `SurfaceListBox` (xmlns:Custom="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008")
control to display a list of elements.

`SurfaceListBox` bind to a

```
   ObservableCollection<Category> _categoriesDot = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
```

`Category` has a property:

```
public bool IsSelectable {get; set;}
```

When an item in `_categoriesDot` has `IsSelectable` to false I need to do not make possible select that item in the `SurfaceListBox`.

Could you please provide a sample of code?

Answer (score 0):

It is a good option to filter only the selectable categories when you populate the _categoriesDot collection.

OR

try setting Focusable property.

```
Focusable="{Binding Path=IsSelectable}"
```